# Laravel : Possible to have 2 dates?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

In our application, we used the date range picker. One of our module have 2 date filter, below is the example filter used by the user.

**Date Filter**

```
date from           : 09-20-2020
date to             : 09-20-2020
date_created from   : 01-01-2020
date_created from   : 12-31-2020
```

**Table schema**

```
name
date
date_created
```

**Model**

```
return DB::table('activities')
            ->whereBetween('date', [date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['start_date'])), date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['end_date']))])
            ->whereBetween('date_created', [date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['creation_date'])), date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['creation_end_date']))])
                ->get()->toArray();
```

Now I want to get all the data within the date and date created

Question: Is it possible to have 2 date filter?

Answer (score 0):

try this in `where()` add callback function

```php
return DB::table('activities')->where(function ($q) use ($data) {
    $q->whereBetween('date', [date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['start_date'])), date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['end_date']))])
        ->whereBetween('date_created', [date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['creation_date'])), date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['creation_end_date']))]);
})->get()->toArray();
```